# JQuery select all values in a dropdown with checkbox not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, flask

I am using Flask as the framework for my application. I have two drop downs with checkboxes which has id "nodes-select" and it will be populated with values that are fetched from the database. Second list has static names. On page load, I have to select all the checkboxes in both the lists. First drop down(nodes-select) is working fine. But second drop down is not selecting any checkbox. I tried this code. Correct me where I am wrong?

**HTML**

```
<body onload = onLoading()>
    <select id="nodes-select" multiple="multiple">
    </select>
    <select id="filter-select" multiple="multiple" >
    </select>
</body>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#nodes-select').change(function(){
    console.log("Atleast nodes...");
    if($("#nodes-select option[value='-1']").is(':selected'))
    {
        console.log("node...");
        $('#nodes-select option').prop('selected', true);
        $("#nodes-select option[value='-1']").prop('selected', false);
    }
    $('#nodes-select').multiselect('refresh');
});

$('#filter-select').change(function(){
    console.log("Atleast filter...");
    if($("#filter-select option[value='-1']").is(':selected'))
    {
        console.log("filter ...");
        $('#filter-select option').prop('selected', true);
        $("#filter-select option[value='-1']").prop('selected', false);
    }
    $('#filter-select').multiselect('refresh');
});

function onLoading()
{
    alert("Page Loaded");
    $.get("/nodes",function(data,status)
          {
        var tmp = data.output; 
        console.log("**"+tmp);
        $('#nodes-select').append($('<option>', {
            value: -1,
            text : "All"
        }));  
        for(var i =0;i<tmp.length;i++)
        {
            console.log(tmp[i]);
            $('#nodes-select').append($('<option>', {
                value: i,
                text : tmp[i]
            }));
        }
        $('#nodes-select').multiselect('rebuild');
        $('#nodes-select option').prop('selected', true);
        $("#nodes-select option[value='-1']").prop('selected', false);
        $('#nodes-select').multiselect('refresh');

        $('#filter-select').append($('<option>', {
            value: -1,
            text : "All"
        })); 
        console.log("&&") ;                       
        var temp = ["MAC","SUBLBL","VRF","IFHNDL","COMP_ID","V4_ADDR","V6_ADDR"];
        for(var i =0;i<temp.length;i++)
        {
            console.log(temp[i]);
            $('#filter-select').append($('<option>', {
                value: i,
                text : temp[i]
            }));
        }
        $('#filter-select').multiselect('rebuild');
        $('#filter-select').prop('selected', true);
        $("#filter-select option[value='-1']").prop('selected', false);
        $('#filter-select').multiselect('refresh');
    });
}            

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are forgetting to query the actual options of #filter-select.

Change this line:

```
$('#filter-select').prop('selected', true);
```

to:

```
$('#filter-select option').prop('selected', true);
```

Comment: Side effects of copy+paste... :D Thanks a lot dude :)

Comment: Great. Can you check the checkmark so i get points for giving you the correct answer.